# Angular 8.0.3 / Angular CLI 8.0.3 unit tests work but since Angular CLI 8.0.4 they failed

Tags: angular, unit-testing

After **Angular 8.0.3 / CLI 8.0.3** to **Angular CLI 8.0.4** migration (and 8.1, 8.2), my unit tests suite failed with:

**An error was thrown in afterAll
  TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined**

The dev and prod run code work well. Only some tests failed. For example all my Angular 8 widgets and pipes tests are OK.

Unit test file:

```js
    import { TestBed }                   from '@angular/core/testing';

    import { AppModule }                 from 'app/app.module';

    import { SourceSetupPanelComponent } from './source-setup-panel.component';

    describe('SourceSetupPanelComponent', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [ AppModule ]
        });
      });

      it('should create an instance', () => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SourceSetupPanelComponent);
        expect(fixture).toBeTruthy();
      });
    });
```

## Main facade directory code.

### **facade.ts** file extract code:

```js
    import {
      BehaviorSubject,
      Observable,
      of as observableOf
    }                        from 'rxjs';
    //
    import { diffs }         from 'classes/tools';
    //
    import {
      OnInit,
      StoreAttRelObs
    }                        from './facade-interface';
    import { FacadeService } from './facade.service';
    //
    import {
      Arity,
      RelationshipSpec
    }                        from './model-interface';
    import * as Models       from './models';
    //
    import { Logger }        from 'classes/logger';
    //
    export abstract class Facade extends Logger implements OnInit {
      static storeAttributesObsList: Array<StoreAttRelObs> = [];
      static storeRelationsObsList:  Array<StoreAttRelObs> = [];
      static _count: BehaviorSubject<number>; // the ACTUAL backend count - this is used by 'getCount'
      //
      static initialize(name: string) {
        // we create a store for all facade, by name
        Object.defineProperty(Facade, name, {
          value: new BehaviorSubject([])
        });
      }
      //
      static storeObservable(name: string): BehaviorSubject<Array<any>> {
        const subject = Facade[name];
        return subject;
      }
      //
      static store(name: string): Array<Facade> {
        if (Facade[name]) {
          return Facade[name].value;
        } else {
          return undefined;
        }
      }
      //
      static next(name: string) {
        Facade[name].next(this.store(name));
      }
      //
      static forObjectRef(objRef: string, entity?: string): Facade {
        const item    = objRef.split('.');
        let className = item[0];

        if ( Facade[className] == null && entity && entity !== className) {
          className = entity;
        }

        const key   = +item[1]; //  convert key string to number
        const store = Facade.store(className);

        if (store) {
          const facade = store.find((f) => f._model._key === key);
          return facade;
        } else {
          return undefined;
        }
      }
      //
      abstract get _model(     );
      abstract set _model(model);
      //
      // Life cycle
      // 1. Model initialization, register as a side effect
      // 2. Facade registration
      // 3. Relationships initialization and override
      //
      constructor(
        readonly facadeService: FacadeService,
        name: string,
      ) {
        super();
      }
      //
      // Meta model
      //
      get attSpec(): Array<string> {
        return Models[this._name]._attSpec;
      }
      get relSpec(): RelationshipSpec {
        return Models[this._name]._relSpec;
      }
      //
      // global attributes setter/getter
      // type checking is done in the derived class
      //
      setAttList(attDesc: any) {
        this._model.setAttList(attDesc);
        this.next();

        const attList = Object.keys(attDesc);
        Facade.attNext(this._name, attList);
      }
      //
      getAtt(name: string) {
        return this._model.getAtt(name);
      }
      //
      setAtt(attName: string, value: string | number | boolean) {
        this._model.setAtt(attName, value);
        this.next();
        Facade.attNext(this._name, [attName]);
      }
      //
      getAttList() {
        return this._model.getAttList();
      }
      //
      // abstract relationship access
      //
      abstract setRel(name: string, value: any): any;
      abstract getRel(name: string)            : any;
      abstract getRelList()                    : any;

    }
```

### **model.ts** file extract code:

```js
    //
    import { environment }  from 'environments/environment';
    //
    import { Logger      }  from 'classes/logger';
    //
    import { ModelService } from './model.service';
    import * as Models      from './models';
    import {
      Arity,
      RelationshipSpec,
    }                       from './model-interface';
    //
    export abstract class Model extends Logger {
      //
      static readonly _cache:  Array<Model> = [];
      //
      private _arity:            Array<Arity> = []; // cache for arities
      private _reverse:          Array<string> = []; // cache for reverse link
      private _snake:            Array<string> = []; // cache for links snake forme
      private _entity:           Array<string> = []; // cache for entity name of a relationship
      private _relationshipList: Array<string> = []; // cache for entity name of a relationship
      //
      readonly _name:          string; // Model name
      readonly _revision:      number; // Model revision key
               _key:           number; // Backend reference
               _att:           any;    // Model attribute object
               _rel:           any;    // Model relation object
               _cachedAtt:     any = {};    // cached attributes object
               _cachedRel:     any = {};    // cached relations object

      //
      // We have a chance to create decent 'dynamic' default values
      //
      static initialize(name: string) {
        // compute attribute list
        Models[name]._attSpec = [];
        Object.keys(Models[name].attDefaultValue).map((key) => {
          Models[name]._attSpec.push(key);
        });
      }
      //
      static lookup(revision: number): Model {
        const result = Model._cache[revision];
        if (result === undefined) {
          Logger.error('lookup -> ', revision, '=', result, Model._cache);
          throw new Error('Cannot lookup entity for key' + revision);
        } else {
          // Logger.info('lookup -> ', entity, key, '=', result);
        }
        return result;
      }
      //
      constructor(
        protected modelService: ModelService,
        name:     string,
        key = 0
      ) {
        super();
        //
        this._name     = name;
        this._revision = modelService.newRevision();
        this._key      = key;
        //
        this.register();
        // ready to link
        // initialize cached value
        this._cachedAtt = this._att;
      }
      //
      get attSpec() {
        return Models[this._name]._attSpec;
      }
      //
      private get relSpec(): Array<RelationshipSpec> {
        return Models[this._name]._relSpec;
      }
      //
      get attDefaultValue() {
        return Models[this._name].attDefaultValue;
      }

      // setter/getter corner
      //
      _attListCheck(attDesc: any) {
        if (environment.attributeExistenceCheck) {
          Object.keys(attDesc).map((key) => {
            // Logger.log(`${this._name}.${this._key} set ${key} ${att[key]}`);
            if (Models[this._name]._attSpec.indexOf(key) === -1) {
              try {
                throw(new Error('Unknown attribute \'' + key + '\' for model \'' + this._name + '\''));
              } catch (err) {
                Logger.warn(err);
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }

      //
      abstract setAttList( attDesc: any ): any;
      abstract getAttList(              ): any ;
      abstract getRelList(              ): any ;
      //
      //
      setAtt(name: string, value: string | number | boolean) {
        this._att[name] = value;
      }
      //
      getAtt(name: string) {
        return this._att[name];
      }
      //
      setRel(name: string, value: any) {
        this._rel[name] = value;
      }
      //
      getRel(name: string) {
        return this._rel[name];
      }
    }
```

### **bases/accessory.tc** file extract code:

```js
    // Generated by model-translator Facade generator
    // Generation Version : 3.0
    // Source             : YAML Madagascar Doctrine files
    // Generated on       : see __info__ file
    //
    import { Facade }        from '../facade';
    import { FacadeService } from '../facade.service';
    //
    // Extensions relashionships
    //
    // Simple relationships
    import { System as ExtensionSystem } from '../extensions/system';
    //
    import {
      Accessory as ModelAccessory,
      AccessoryAtt,
    } from '../models/accessory';

    // Accessory Facade
    //
    // Facade Relationships
    export class AccessoryRel {
      // Simple relationships
      system: ExtensionSystem = null;
    }
    //
    export class Accessory extends Facade {
      //
      // Class fields and methods
      //
      // Contains all information for the Facade
      //
      __model: ModelAccessory;
      //
      // Relationhips cache
      //
      _rel = new AccessoryRel();
      // Simple relationships
      //
      // Add a new Accessory to the list and link if necessary
      //
      constructor(
        facadeService: FacadeService,
        att:           Partial<AccessoryAtt> = {},
        rel:           Partial<AccessoryRel> = {},
        key = 0
      ) {
        super(facadeService, 'Accessory');
        this.__model = new ModelAccessory(this.facadeService.modelService, att, key);
        this.register();
        if (key) {
          this.initRelations(rel);
        } else {
          this.link(rel);
        }
        this.onInit();
      }
      //
      set _model(model: ModelAccessory) {
        this.__model = model;
      }
      //
      get _model(): ModelAccessory {
        return this.__model;
      }
      //
      setAttList(attDesc: Partial<AccessoryAtt>) {
        super.setAttList(attDesc);
      }
      //
      setAtt(name: string, value: string | number | boolean) {
        super.setAtt(name, value);
      }
      //
      getAtt(name: string) {
        return super.getAtt(name);
      }
      //
      getAttList(): AccessoryAtt {
        return super.getAttList();
      }
      //
      setRel(name: string, value: any) {
        this._rel[name] = value;
      }
      //
      getRel(name: string) {
        return this._rel[name];
      }
      //
      getRelList(): AccessoryRel {
        return this._rel;
      }
      //
      link(linkDescription: Partial<AccessoryRel>) {
        super.link(linkDescription);
      }
      //
      get name(): string {
        return this.getAttList().name;
      }
      //
      set name(name: string) {
        this.setAttList({ name });
      }
      //
      get brand(): string {
        return this.getAttList().brand;
      }
      //
      set brand(brand: string) {
        this.setAttList({ brand });
      }
      //
      get model(): string {
        return this.getAttList().model;
      }
      //
      set model(model: string) {
        this.setAttList({ model });
      }
      //
      get quantity(): number {
        return this.getAttList().quantity;
      }
      //
      set quantity(quantity: number) {
        this.setAttList({ quantity });
      }
      //
      get product_code(): string {
        return this.getAttList().product_code;
      }
      //
      set product_code(product_code: string) {
        this.setAttList({ product_code });
      }
      //
      get system(): ExtensionSystem {
        return this._rel.system;
      }
      //
      set system(system: ExtensionSystem) {
        this.updateLink( { system } );
      }
    }
    //
```

### **extensions/accessory.tc** file extract code:

```js
    //
    import { FacadeService }      from '../facade.service';
    //
    import { AccessoryAtt }       from '../models/accessory';
    import {
        Accessory as BaseAccessory,
        AccessoryRel
    }                             from '../bases/accessory';
    //
    //
    export class Accessory extends BaseAccessory {
      //
      constructor(
        facadeService: FacadeService,
        att:          Partial<AccessoryAtt> = {},
        rel:          Partial<AccessoryRel> = {},
        key = 0
      ) {
        //
        super(facadeService, att, rel, key);
      }
      //
      onInit() {
        //
      }
      //
    }
```

### **models/accessory.tc** file extract code:

```js
    // Generated by model-translator Facade generator
    // Generation Version : 3.0
    // Source             : YAML Madagascar Doctrine files
    // Generated on       : see __info__ file
    // tslint:disable:max-line-length
    //
    import { ModelService } from '../model.service';
    import {
      Arity,
      RelationshipSpec
    }                       from '../model-interface';
    import { Model }        from '../model';
    //
    // Attributes
    export class AccessoryAtt {
      name         = '';
      brand        = '';
      model        = '';
      quantity     = 0;
      product_code = '';
    }

    const DEFAULT_VALUE = new AccessoryAtt();

    // Model Relationships
    export class AccessoryRel {
      // Simple relationships
      system = 0;
    }
    //
    export class Accessory extends Model {
      // Meta-model info
      static readonly _attSpec: Array<string>;
      //
      static readonly _relSpec: Array<RelationshipSpec> = [
        // Simple relationships
        { link: 'system', arity: Arity.Simple  , name: 'system', entity: 'System', reverse: 'accessoryList' },
      ];
      //
      // For external access
      static readonly attDefaultValue: AccessoryAtt = DEFAULT_VALUE;
      //
      constructor(
        protected modelService: ModelService,
        att:      Partial<AccessoryAtt> = {},
        key = 0
      ) {
        super(modelService, 'Accessory', key);
        this._att = new AccessoryAtt();
        this._rel = new AccessoryRel();
        this._att = {...DEFAULT_VALUE, ...att};
      }
      //
      setAttList(attDesc: AccessoryAtt) {
        super._attListCheck(attDesc);
        return super._setAttList(attDesc);
      }
      //
      getAttList(): AccessoryAtt {
        return this._att as AccessoryAtt;
      }
      //
      getRelList(): AccessoryRel {
        return this._rel as AccessoryRel;
      }
      //
    }
```

Circular dependencies warning messages:

```sh
    WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
    src/app/facade/model.ts -> src/app/facade/models/index.ts -> src/app/facade/models/accessory.ts -> src/app/facade/model.ts


    WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
    src/app/facade/models/accessory.ts -> src/app/facade/model.ts -> src/app/facade/models/index.ts -> src/app/facade/models/accessory.ts


    WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
    src/app/facade/models/index.ts -> src/app/facade/models/accessory.ts -> src/app/facade/model.ts -> src/app/facade/models/index.ts
```

PS: I just added one class of our model to try to simplify... (we have more than 80 classes)

Comment: consider posting some code, it would make it easier for others to help you with your specific problem

Comment: I know but this is a very huge project and I cannot post all the code... I just want first if someone else has this kind of issue when migrating from Angular CLI 8.0.3 to 8.0.4. And maybe what has changed around webpack...

Comment: I understand that, but consider posting one of your tests which fail, very hard for people to answer without seeing your code

Comment: Our **facade** main directory that contains the model generated code is structured like this: ones **bases** directory with classes and index.ts file, one **extensions** with classes and index.ts and one **models** with classes and index.ts too. The facade dir contains a facade.ts file (used by facade.service.ts) and a model.ts (used by model.service.ts). Ath high level in extensions dir, each class extends the facade one. A class can import zero or more classes. This is why we have circular dependencies...

Answer (score 0):

Same situation here.

After npm update/upgrade few days ago new "WARNING in Circular dependency detected" messages appeared.

This happens on Parent - Child with reference to Parent classes on different .ts files.

For example:

File voyage.ts

```
import { VoyageWork } from './voyageWork';

export class Voyage {
  voyageWorks: VoyageWork[] = [];

  // ...
}
```

File voyageWork.ts

```
import { Voyage } from './voyage';

export class VoyageWork {
  voyage: Voyage;

  constructor(voyage: Voyage) {
    this.voyage = voyage;
  }

  // ...
}
```

The "unique" solution found is to put all the classes on the same file... terrible.